# Why does the UnboundLocalError showing variable referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code and the error are attached below. I tried starting the variable inside the define function also but I did not get the result still, it still shows the same error. This is a tkinter code to spam mail someone, but as the variable could not be assigned properly I am not able to run it.

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib
global variable
variable = 0
root = Tk()



window_size = ("800x500")
root.configure(background='black')

root.geometry(window_size)

root.title('spam  mail    ' + window_size)

frame = LabelFrame(root,padx=50,pady=50)
frame.grid(padx=100,pady=100)

label1 = Label(frame,text="TYPE SENDER'S MAIL ADRESS HERE")
label1.grid(row=1,column=0)


gmail_adress_textbox = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_textbox.grid(row=2,column=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE SUBJECT HERE")
label2.grid(row=3,column=0)


gmail_adress_subject = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_subject.grid(row=4,column=0)


label3 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE BODY HERE")
label3.grid(row=5,column=0)


gmail_adress_body = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_body.grid(row=6,column=0)

label4 = Label(frame,text="""NO OF TIMES YOU WANT TO SEND 
    (NOTE SENDING MORE THAN 10 MAILS WILL TAKE MORE TIME)""")
label4.grid(row=7,column=0)

answeruser = Entry(frame,width=50)
answeruser.grid(row=8,column=0)




def sendit():
    EMAIL_ADRESS = "removed for question"



    EMAIL_PASSWORD = "removed for question"
    SENDERSMAILID = gmail_adress_textbox.get()



    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        subject = gmail_adress_subject.get()
        body = gmail_adress_body.get()

        msg = 'subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADRESS, SENDERSMAILID, msg)


        label4 = Label(frame,text="YOUR MAIL HAS BEEN SENT")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=0)

        variable += 1



def spammer():
    while variable != answeruser:
        label5 = Label(frame, text=variable).grid(row=11,column=0)


        sendit()

button_send = Button(frame,text="send",command=spammer)
button_send.grid(row=9,column=0)


root.mainloop()
TK_SILENCE_DEPRECIATION=1
```

ERROR:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/sanjaymarison/PycharmProjects/gui/gui.py", line 85, in spammer
    sendit()
  File "/Users/sanjaymarison/PycharmProjects/gui/gui.py", line 76, in sendit
    variable += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You need to define it as a `global` variable.Just add `global variable` in the function `sendit()`.Refer [python-scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: You have an indentation on your first line. Is it in in your code or is it a typo while typing your question?

Comment: Works for me in my machine. Are you using Python version 3 or version 2?

Comment: I add a global variable inside the function and it worked. Don't know why this happened, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib
variable = 0
root = Tk()

window_size = ("800x500")
root.configure(background='black')
root.geometry(window_size)
root.title('spam  mail    ' + window_size)

frame = LabelFrame(root,padx=50,pady=50)
frame.grid(padx=100,pady=100)

label1 = Label(frame,text="TYPE SENDER'S MAIL ADRESS HERE")
label1.grid(row=1,column=0)


gmail_adress_textbox = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_textbox.grid(row=2,column=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE SUBJECT HERE")
label2.grid(row=3,column=0)


gmail_adress_subject = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_subject.grid(row=4,column=0)


label3 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE BODY HERE")
label3.grid(row=5,column=0)


gmail_adress_body = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_body.grid(row=6,column=0)

label4 = Label(frame,text="""NO OF TIMES YOU WANT TO SEND 
   (NOTE SENDING MORE THAN 10 MAILS WILL TAKE MORE TIME)""")
label4.grid(row=7,column=0)

answeruser = Entry(frame,width=50)
answeruser.grid(row=8,column=0)




def sendit(parameter):
    EMAIL_ADRESS = "removed for question"

    EMAIL_PASSWORD = "removed for question"
    SENDERSMAILID = gmail_adress_textbox.get()

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        subject = gmail_adress_subject.get()
        body = gmail_adress_body.get()

        msg = 'subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADRESS, SENDERSMAILID, msg)

        label4 = Label(frame,text="YOUR MAIL HAS BEEN SENT")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=0)

        parameter += 1
        return parameter



def spammer(x):
    while x != answeruser:
        label5 = Label(frame, text=variable).grid(row=11,column=0)
        x = sendit(x)

button_send = Button(frame, text="send",command=spammer(variable))  
# or any other way to give the spammer function "variable" as parameter
button_send.grid(row=9,column=0)
root.mainloop()
TK_SILENCE_DEPRECIATION=1
```

Comment: Add some information about the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by declaring the variable global and also using global inside the function.

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib
global variable
variable = 0
root = Tk()



window_size = ("800x500")
root.configure(background='black')

root.geometry(window_size)

root.title('spam  mail    ' + window_size)

frame = LabelFrame(root,padx=50,pady=50)
frame.grid(padx=100,pady=100)

label1 = Label(frame,text="TYPE SENDER'S MAIL ADRESS HERE")
label1.grid(row=1,column=0)


gmail_adress_textbox = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_textbox.grid(row=2,column=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE SUBJECT HERE")
label2.grid(row=3,column=0)


gmail_adress_subject = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_subject.grid(row=4,column=0)


label3 = Label(frame,text="TYPE THE BODY HERE")
label3.grid(row=5,column=0)


gmail_adress_body = Entry(frame,width=50)
gmail_adress_body.grid(row=6,column=0)

label4 = Label(frame,text="""NO OF TIMES YOU WANT TO SEND 
    (NOTE SENDING MORE THAN 10 MAILS WILL TAKE MORE TIME)""")
label4.grid(row=7,column=0)

answeruser = Entry(frame,width=50)
answeruser.grid(row=8,column=0)




def sendit():
    EMAIL_ADRESS = "removed for question"



    EMAIL_PASSWORD = "removed for question"
    SENDERSMAILID = gmail_adress_textbox.get()



    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)

        subject = gmail_adress_subject.get()
        body = gmail_adress_body.get()

        msg = 'subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'

        smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADRESS, SENDERSMAILID, msg)


        label4 = Label(frame,text="YOUR MAIL HAS BEEN SENT")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=0)
        global variable
        variable += 1



def spammer():
    global variable
    while variable != answeruser:
        label5 = Label(frame, text=variable).grid(row=11,column=0)


        sendit()

button_send = Button(frame,text="send",command=spammer)
button_send.grid(row=9,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Saying `global` outside of functions will do no good.

Comment: @CoolCloud can you explain i am not able to understand

Comment: You can remove `global` that is outside of functions